# How to change toolbar and tab color after CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android

I want to change the color of Collapsed Toolbar Layout(Red) to other color. How can I change that? I have given the image and my code sample below.I have tried to change through `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"`, but it not working.  Thanks in advance.

[image: Initial Image]

[image: Image after collapsing]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bgimage"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

```
MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.htab_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Parallax Tabs");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.htab_viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.htab_collapse_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);

        ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ln);

        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                int vibrantColor = palette.getVibrantColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
                int vibrantDarkColor = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(vibrantColor);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(vibrantDarkColor);
            }
        });

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        showToast("One");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        showToast("Two");

                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }


    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(/*getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_material_light)*/), "CAT");
        adapter.addFrag(new DummyFragment(/*getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light)*/), "DOG");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {


            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public static class DummyFragment extends Fragment {
        int color;
        SimpleRecyclerAdapter adapter;

        public DummyFragment() {
        }

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public DummyFragment(int color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_fragment, container, false);

            final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_bg);
            //frameLayout.setBackgroundColor();

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dummyfrag_scrollableview);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


String text = "I am praveen";
            adapter = new SimpleRecyclerAdapter(loadContentString());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;
        }

        private String loadContentString() {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            String content = "";
            try {
                inputStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("lorem.txt");
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                content = outputStream.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                closeSilently(inputStream);
                closeSilently(outputStream);
            }

            return content;
        }

        public void closeSilently(Closeable c) {
            if (c == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}

SimpleRecyclerAdapter.java
public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleRecyclerAdapter.VersionViewHolder> {
String versionModels;

OnItemClickListener clickListener;


public SimpleRecyclerAdapter(String versionModels) {
    this.versionModels = versionModels;
}

@Override
public VersionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerlist_item, viewGroup, false);
    VersionViewHolder viewHolder = new VersionViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VersionViewHolder versionViewHolder, int i) {

        versionViewHolder.title.setText(versionModels);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
}


class VersionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title;
    TextView subTitle;

    public VersionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_name);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

}

```
dummy_fragment.xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dummyfrag_scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"/>
```

```
recyclerlist_item.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android version name"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post code for `style.xml`

Comment: are you sure your `colorPrimary` in `color.xml` is not red.

Comment: <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color> this is the two value I am having in colors.xml that is not in red.

Comment: this seems to be good. please post all your code in java.

Comment: I have posted my full code here. Can you pls find me solution for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96543/discussion-between-vipul-asri-and-praveenkumar).